# jtable multiple cell selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell

Is it possible to select multiple non adjacent cells in java using jtable ? if not, is there an alternative to this ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JTable table = ...

ListSelectionModel selModel = table.getSelectionModel();
selModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
```